# How do you access a module located in a .jar file using python?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have a python script that attempts to import a package from a test.jar file. Located in the test.jar file when extracted is a path following the initial folder of test (com->test->meeting and in meeting is the Stats.class file). I used the import statement 'from com.test.meeting import Stats'. The resulting error is
'''
from com.test.meeting import Stats
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com'
'''
How would I make it so that these packages in the jar file are discoverable from my python program that is located in the same working directory?

Comment: Not sure you can with regular python, I think you need to use Jython for that. Jython is run on the JVM and can access Java packages, Python doesn't have that ability

Comment: Is this python or jython? Is the class file you're referring to a python file or a java class?